# ¿Debería borrar cortesías mientras estoy editando una publicación de otro usuario?

Tags: discusión, moderación, convenciones-sociales

Hace un tiempo me llamó la atención que varios usuarios borran completamente sin remplazo frases de cortesía, como un "Hola" al principio de la pregunta, o un "Gracias por su tiempo" al final.

Entiendo perfectamente porque es beneficioso evitar publicaciones que consistan **nada más** que en un "Gracias" o "Yo también". Sin embargo, lo siento como un exceso de autoridad si simplemente borro cualquier cortesía que encuentro.

¡Ojo!, estoy hablando aquí de preguntas y respuestas, que después de su redacción tienen un valor informativo más allá del agradecimiento o saludo, no de publicaciones que no aportan nada. Entiendo también que éstas no se salvan solamente porque terminan con un gracias.

Answer (score 14):

Esto ya se ha hablado en Meta SE: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/182862). La [respuesta aceptada y más votada por la comunidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/182862) dice:

> I've always been against the greetings and salutations (along with other extraneous clutter) in questions for a number of reasons:
>
> 1. It will leave even less room in the question preview so that we have more difficulty gauging what a question consists of by reading the preview.
> 2. It takes time to read and parse through those questions when I am trying to spend my time more efficiently reading through the actual question and figuring out how to appropriately answer it. If I have to start reading all the little side comments and snarky humor inserted in there it detracts from the overall message.
> 3. If this is supposed to be a website which is servicing more than just the primary author, we need to think about how we construct messages so that they appear more clearly to those searching on google for questions that match their own. If I am looking for a solution for question X, I want to find someone who had the same problem, not their short autobiography and formalities before getting to that actual question.

Traducido:

> Siempre he estado en contra de los saludos y expresiones [de gratitud y demás](junto con otros desórdenes extraños) en las preguntas por un conjunto de razones:
>
> 1. Deja mucho menos espacio en la vista rápida (preview) de la pregunta. Esto nos da más dificultad al tratar de comprender de qué consiste con tan solo leer esa vista rápida.
> 2. Toma tiempo leer y parsear a través de estas preguntas cuando intento gastar mi tiempo más eficientemente leyendo la pregunta actual y determinar cómo responderla apropiadamente. Si tuviese que leer todos los pequeños comentarios y el sarcasmo ingresado allí me quita tiempo del mensaje en general.
> 3. Si se supone que es un sitio que sirve más que solo al autor de la pregunta, necesitamos pensar en cómo construimos mensajes que sean más claros para buscar en Google para que las preguntas coincidan por sí solas. Si busco la solución por una pregunta X, quiero encontrar a alguien que haya tenido el mismo problema, no su corta auto biografía y formalidades antes de leer la pregunta concreta.

Como parte de ello, la cortesía en StackOverflow<sup>1</sup> en general no se basa en colocar "Hola", "Saludos", "Gracias" ni nada de eso. Si estás agradecido, vota a favor, y si una respuesta resuelve la pregunta que publicaste, acéptala, ese es el mayor signo de gratitud aquí. Considera que StackOverflow en general tiene unas [reglas para borrar este contenido automáticamente al publicar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/182862) (la segunda respuesta de la pregunta indica al inicio de esta publicación). Quizás no funciona en español o hay muchas maneras de sacarle la vuelta.

Estoy a favor de remover este tipo de "etiqueta" de las preguntas, que no se enfocan en lo que se basa el sitio: **preguntas y respuestas concretas**. Todo lo que es conversación informal se puede realizar en las [salas de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com).

Referente a firmas o lemas en las publicaciones, existe una [página de faq al respecto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/182862):

> In general, **taglines and signatures are strongly discouraged**, and are likely to be edited out.

Traducido:

> En general, **los lemas y firmas están fuertemente desaprobados**, y es muy probable que se remuevan en una edición.

---

<sup>1</sup> La empresa se llama StackOverflow no StackExchange. Fuente: https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/

Comment: Este comentario esta fuera del tema. Una lema es un comentario como los "Fulanito se siente amurrado" en facebook, y signaturas son una tradición (o antitradicion) de foros, como citas o banners. No me refiero a eso. Como viven ustedes sus días, estilo "Pasame la mantequilla, weon?" o "Me podrías acercar la mermelada? Gracias"? Ademas, ni en SO ingles hacen una regla de eso, solamente dicen que taglines y signaturas **probablemente** sean eliminados. En realidad existe una política de StackOverflow que pide amigabilidad entre los usuarios.

Comment: Sí, la hay. Está en el primer enlace que coloqué en la pregunta.

Comment: No dice nada de agradecimientos. Acepto la información sobre los saludos. personalmente no los vi critico.

Comment: @StefanNolde respuesta actualizada para apuntar primero respecto a lo que indicas.

Comment: Traducir "Salutation" con "expresión de gratitud" es cuestionable. Una "Salutation" es por ejemplo un "Dear Sirs" o un "Your`s Faithfully". En todo caso por ahora la señal esta claro para mi, cortesía esta considerado una obstrucción de la información.

Comment: @StefanNolde en realidad traduje "greetings and salutations" como "saludos y expresiones [de gratitud y demás]", nótese el cambio del orden. En español, no se lee muy bien decirlo al revés.

Comment: Traducir "Greetings" así funciona menos. "Greetings" are "Hi!", What's up?" etc.

Comment: @StefanNolde la idea es: todo eso es irrelevante. No va. Punto final.

Comment: hhah no habia visto en que consistia el edit de @LuiggiMendoza xDD que ironico en esta pregunta xD

Comment: @lois6b [la ironía](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2816970539/092b1803fcbe2b22f95acc4e80a44847_400x400.jpeg)...

Answer (score -3):

No, no las borres.

Nuestra comunidad es diferente a la anglosajona y hay muchos usuarios que gustan de las cortesías y de un trato más amigable y menos aséptico. Muchos usuarios nos dedicamos profesionalmente a esto. Pero muchos lo hacemos también por afición, o solo por afición.

Esto se nota en la existencia (en el momento de redactar esta respuesta) de preguntas y respuestas que incluyen esas cortesías sin ningún voto negativo, con positivos y que existen desde hace semanas, meses o incluso más de un año.

Ejemplos:
[¿Cómo acceder a localhost desde cualquier equipo de una red doméstica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39712/c%C3%B3mo-acceder-a-localhost-desde-cualquier-equipo-de-una-red-dom%C3%A9stica)
[¿Cómo se referencia un archivo php en Ajax que está en otro directorio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38698/c%c3%b3mo-se-referencia-un-archivo-php-en-ajax-que-est%c3%a1-en-otro-directorio)
[Cómo ejecutar acciones del metodo on(change, sin cambiar manualmente el valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35628/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-acciones-del-metodo-onchange-sin-cambiar-manualmente-el-valor)
[Cómo hacer que aparezca la fecha actual en el input asociado a un datepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35414/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-aparezca-la-fecha-actual-en-el-input-asociado-a-un-datepicker)
[¿Cómo obtener dos filas de una sola fila en una consulta a MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/916/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-dos-filas-de-una-sola-fila-en-una-consulta-a-mysql)
[¿Cuál es la mejor forma de guardar fechas en SQLite?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/821/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-mejor-forma-de-guardar-fechas-en-sqlite)
[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre wait() y sleep() en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-wait-y-sleep-en-java)
[Spectrogram[Array] a espectrograma en 3D, Listplot3d](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363/spectrogramarray-a-espectrograma-en-3d-listplot3d)
[¿Para qué es el branch “gh-pages” que aparece en muchos repos de GitHub?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2577/para-qu%c3%a9-es-el-branch-gh-pages-que-aparece-en-muchos-repos-de-github)
[Cómo almacenar varias instancias de un objeto en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5030/c%c3%b3mo-almacenar-varias-instancias-de-un-objeto-en-java)
[IndexOf() buscar palabra en una frase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9701/indexof-buscar-palabra-en-una-frase)
Respuesta a [Cómo determinar si todos los dígitos de un número entero son iguales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33325/c%C3%B3mo-determinar-si-todos-los-d%C3%ADgitos-de-un-n%C3%BAmero-entero-son-iguales/33375?s=6%7C0.0605#33375)

La última tiene un voto en contra pero la incluyo porque +33/-1 es un resultado excelente.

Yo personalmente no acostumbro a poner cortesías.Y tampoco me gustan demasiado. Pero el verdadero respeto se demuestra respetando a quien no está de acuerdo contigo, poco mérito tiene el respetar a quien comparte tu opinión. Respetemos el deseo de quien usa cortesías. Unas palabras amables que ocupen una porción pequeña del texto no hacen daño a nadie.

Comment: Aunque no lo comparto, me parece interesante el argumento de que los usuarios de aquí pueden ser más dados a cortesías, etc. Lo que no creo que sea un argumento de peso es que esas publicaciones con cortesías tengan votos a favor. ¡Sería bastante fuerte que la gente votara en contra por el simple hecho de que tuvieran saludos o despidos! Como siempre, votamos por contenido, no por cosas tangenciales.

Comment: Yo, y sospecho que muchos otros, votaría negativo en una pregunta/respuesta que dedicase docenas de líneas a cortesías. Estos ejemplos de preguntas/respuestas muestran que el tamaño que dedican a cortesías es al menos tolerable por la mayor parte de la comunidad. Algunas son bastante populares, por lo que son representativas de esa tolerancia.

Answer (score -9):

En mi opinión la mejor práctica sería de (bajo del principio de redacción "mejora lo necesario, cambia lo menos que posible, la pregunta no fue tuya") limitarse a mejorar la entendibilidad de las publicaciónes pero respetar el estilo del autor original (si hay uno reconocible). Eso implica que no voy a borrar todas "Holas" y "Gracias" en las publicaciones mientras aparte de ellos la publicación tiene un valor informativo. Cada persona tiene un derecho a ser cortés.

También sería mejor práctica de pedir usuarios de evitar publicaciones que se dedican **únicamente** a cortesías u opiniones, porque para eso hay votos y la posibilidad de aceptar respuestas.

Comment: Suelo editar bastante este tipo de cosas, pero normalmente si es que de paso tengo que editar la publicacion. Solo edito esto y nada más cuando es un: "Hola me llamo A y llevo poco programando en X espero me puedan ayudar...." o algunos que son *demasiado*  coloquiales  como "Hola amigos como están, si me pueden ayudar ...."

Comment: En mi opinión, no se trata de _cada persona tiene un derecho de ser cortés_, todos los somos, pero los sitios de Stack Exchage son sitios de **preguntas y respuestas**. La respuesta de Luiggi resume la posición de los usuarios en cuanto a la "etiqueta" al generar y responder preguntas en los sitios de Stack Exchange.

Comment: No lo tomes a mal, la idea general es mantener el visibilidad al maximo. Y recuerda como dice Luiggi el mejor agradecimiento es el +1 o aceptar la respuesta

Comment: @jasilva Si sientes que hay que borrar gracias (y me refiero a gracias como  parte de una contribución con contenido de valor en general), porqué agregas un "No lo tomas a mal"? pensaba que cortesía no es necesaria, ni bienvenida en SOes ;) Luiggi tiene razón en lo que dijo, sin embargo nadie en realidad siente así, o no hubieras dicho lo ue dijiste como lo dijiste