# ¿Se considera ruido dar un mensaje de buenos dias independiente la zona horaria en las respuestas?

Tags: discusión

hace poco a través de un comentario en una de mis respuestas en *stackoverflow* un colaborador de buena reputacion me comentó que dar saludos de buenos dias se consideraba **Ruido**; por lo que indague en la  seccion de *preguntas y respuestas* del sitio pero no encontre nada al respecto por lo que mi duda consiste en saber si ¿Verdaderamente se considera ruido un saludo de buenos dias al principio de la respuesta?

Comment: Si bien concuerdo en que no aporta mucho a la respuesta, no lo considero como "Ruido". Deberías ser capaz de poder dar ese tipo de marcas personales a tus respuestas (si lo deseas) y no veo que comprometan para nada el formato de la misma. De hecho, uno de los colaboradores más asiduos y con alta reputación siempre comienza sus respuestas con *Buen día*, y  no por ello sus respuestas dejan de ser excelentes.

Comment: Existe hace tiempo un artículo llamado [Escribiendo la pregunta perfecta](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (que aplica también a las respuestas) que en la sección titulada *Making a good impression* establece lo siguiente: *There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and “Thanks – hope to get an answer soon” in the question. These will often be edited out by other users, as they’re basically a distraction*. No estoy seguro de si este artículo está traducido al castellano. Saludos

Comment: Este tema ya ha salido con anterioridad en [¿Debería borrar cortesías mientras estoy editando una publicación de otro usuario?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334/deber%c3%ada-borrar-cortes%c3%adas-mientras-estoy-editando-una-publicaci%c3%b3n-de-otro-usuari). La respuesta mas votada fué `... las cortesias son ruido que no aportan nada a la pregunta/respuesta ...`, opinión que comparto. Simpre habrá quién las use ... y siempre habrá quien las elimine editando (yo, por ejemplo).

Comment: Existe otra razón aún más técnica, y es que: *Greetings at the start of a question are particularly useless as they can take up valuable space in the snippet displayed in the question list.*

Comment: Lo unico que puedo decirte es que una vez lei que si vas a preguntar algo y comienzas como con "hola, como estan, buenos dias" y no vas directo a la pregunta eso quita tiempo de respuesta. pero de hacer ruido, osea de despertar que se yo, pues para eso existe silenciar las notificaciones XD

Comment: Sí, lo siento pero para mi es puro ruido, no aporta absolutamente nada a la respuesta. Tal como muchas veces decimos **esto no es un foro** y las referencias personales o subjetivas deberían estar fuera de lo que publicamos en preguntas o respuestas. Decir "Buenos dias" es subjetivo. Para mi no son siempre buenos y no empiezo mis publicaciones diciendo "Vaya día más feo que me espera" :-).  ¿Que es cortés decirlo?  Sin duda alguna, pero aquí no creo que eso importe en una respuesta que procura ser técnica normalmente, y por ello lo considero ruido.  Normalmente, si edito una pregunta, lo borro

Comment: Para mí si solo pones un "hola" gracias al principio y un "gracias" al final no le veo problema, al final detrás de nuestros mensajes hay personas y a veces es símplemente natural ser cordial y educado. Otra cosa es que pongas "Hola a todos/todas espero que estéis disfrutando un verano estupendo, que Dios os bendiga gracias de antebrazo". Ahí ya si que lo veo innecesario.

Comment: Si, por ejemplo, quiero recopilar algunas respuestas que me interesan, me sobran los saludos si o si, pues tan solo me interesa la parte técnica de la respuesta. Este sitio, que yo sepa, pretende recopilar preguntas y respuestas concretas simplemente, y obviar cualquier coloquialismo posible. Tal como dicen en [ask]: _El primer párrafo en tu pregunta es la segunda cosa que la mayoría de lectores verán, así que hazlo de la forma más atractiva e informativa posible._ y si lo que ven es un saludo no se yo...

Comment: Pregunta en meta relacionada: [Saludar o no saludar](/q/4282)

Comment: Creo que StackExchange tiene una filosofía terrible. Como un voto a favor es un gesto de cortesía que reemplace a los saludos?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Debería borrar cortesías mientras estoy editando una publicación de otro usuario?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334/deber%c3%ada-borrar-cortes%c3%adas-mientras-estoy-editando-una-publicaci%c3%b3n-de-otro-usuari)

Comment: Saludar no _es malo_. Si la vista principal de un sitio en SE muestra _el comienzo_ de una pregunta, sería _poco práctico_ ver un listado de _buenos días, hola, hola compañeros tengo un problema_ que no ayuda en nada a saber de qué va la pregunta (piensen en ese resumen que muestra gmail). Entonces, son cosas separadas el que _sea malo_ y el que _haga ruido_. Como "buena práctica" podría asimilarse a "darle un buen SEO a tu pregunta" para que te respondan rápido

Answer (score 8):

#### Saludar en otros entornos

Este debate va más allá de Stack Exchange. Es un detalle de la sociedad humana en general.

Como le dije a Mauricio en un comentario allí: si ser amables y cordiales genera ruido, entonces no deberíamos de ser así. Por ejemplo, en el trabajo o las instituciones de estudio, o en una llamada formal, tendríamos que dejar de lado el saludo y enfocarnos a lo que vinimos. No me suena bien hacer eso.

Para mi, siempre que el saludo sea corto, no le veo ningún problema. Es verdad que si vas a un funeral, no deberías decir "buenos dias" y sonreir. Pero si saludar.

En conclusión, que el entorno requiera de concentración en ciertos temas (sea un sitio serio de preguntas y respuestas, como una oficina) no justifica que no se deba saludar a la gente.

Cito el comentario de ordago con el cual estoy de acuerdo:

> Para mí si solo pones un "hola" gracias al principio y un "gracias" al
> final no le veo problema, al final detrás de nuestros mensajes hay
> personas y a veces es símplemente natural ser cordial y educado. Otra
> cosa es que pongas "Hola a todos/todas espero que estéis disfrutando
> un verano estupendo, que Dios os bendiga gracias de antebrazo". Ahí ya
> si que lo veo innecesario.

#### Los saludos entonces NO son ruido?

De hecho, saludar es ruido en las preguntas y respuestas, ya que realmente no aporta nada de información valiosa a la publicación. Pero hay ruido que no merece ser eliminado. Los saludos son un lindo pequeño gesto, por que eliminarlos?

Si es un lindo gesto, y es cortito, no creo que merezca ser borrado.

#### Conclusión

Que esto **no** sea un foro no cambia el hecho de que se pueda ser una persona amable y saludar. Y no estoy de acuerdo con la filosofía de Stack Exchange de 0 ruido.