# Comportamiento cuestionable de un usuario

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Hace unos días recibí notificaciones de que mis publicaciones habían sido editadas. Todo normal hasta ahí.

Al revisar los cambios me percaté de que las únicas modificaciones eran cambiar las palabras **arreglo** por **array**. Realmente no mejoran ningún aspecto de la publicación. Parece más una preferencia del editor del empleo de una palabra sobre la otra.

Reviso los cambios de la segunda publicación y nuevamente, solo las palabras **arreglo** habían sido cambiadas por **array**. Decidí revisar quien era el autor de las modificaciones. Se trataba del mismo usuario, [unknow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/108641/unknow). Lo dejé pasar, revertí y no dije nada.

Hoy padaleiana [mencionó en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62614589#62614589) que el usuario sigue haciendo modificaciones del estilo. Además mostró que, no conforme con editar las publicaciones una sola vez, persiste en que queden expresadas en base a su preferencia. [3 veces hizo cambios que fueron revertidos y los volvió a hacer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/574538/revisions).

Esto no parece una simple preferencia, sino una obsesión.

Revisé sus [modificaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/108641/unknow?tab=activity&sort=revisions) y llegué a la conclusión de que:

- Comenzó a hacer ese tipo de cambios [desde diciembre de 2019](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/312949/4).
- Desde el 19 de julio de 2021 casi todos son cambios de **arreglo** por **array**.
- Entre febrero y mayo de 2021 hizo cambios en etiquetas de otras preguntas y no parecen necesarios. Por ejemplo en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/426555/169744).

Al parecer su comportamiento pasó desapercibido un buen tiempo, hasta que se salió de control en este mes y lo detectamos.

Hay que hacer algo para frenarlo.

**Espero que esta publicación llegue al usuario involucrado y pueda explicar por qué lo hace. Sino resolver, como mínimo, revocarle el permiso de edición.**

---

Teniendo en cuenta la situación, noto que al sitio le falta la posibilidad de reportar ediciones. Podría ser una forma más simple de que las personas con el privilegio estén al tanto.

Agradecería que me dijeran si prefieren que haga una nueva publicación exclusivamente para la propuesta de la característica.

Comment: En cuanto a "noto que al sitio le falta la posibilidad de reportar ediciones": me parece que el reporte _se necesita la intervención de un moderador_ bastaría para tales casos.

Comment: @padaleiana seguro? Pensé que esa sección solo aplica para las preguntas y sus autores originales.

Comment: hay que restringirle al usuario la edicion de preguntas y respuesta ...

Comment: Sí, estoy segura :)

Comment: Falta que el usuario en cuestión edite esta pregunta para cambiar *arreglo* por *array*. :/

Comment: Cerrarle la cuenta si más.

Comment: Me paso lo mismo con ese usuario hace par de dias y la verdad me llamo la atencion que hiciera eso, yo voto por que le quiten el permiso de edicion o le bloqueen la cuenta por un tiempo

Comment: El usuario @unknow ya hace bastante tiempo que tiene ese tipo de ediciones, siempre las rechazo, pero luego de un tiempo vuelve, nunca le di importancia pero ahora que lo pienso si es algo raro jeje, Ahora veo que ya tiene reputación para modificación directa, creo que será algo peligroso XD

Comment: Yo esta semana retracté 3 ó 4 veces unas de mis publicaciones que editó! Tuve que mandar un reporte!

Comment: @HeytalePazguato sí, justamente es el historial de ediciones de tu respuesta el que me llevó a hacer mi comentario en el chat (y fue el que enlacé y se enlazó en la pregunta también). De verdad pareciera una _obsesión_.

Comment: Lo siento pero hasta que la acepción esté incluida en el diccionario de la Lengua Española (https://dle.rae.es/arreglo) me va a seguir pareciendo un término incorrecto, y me va a seguir pareciendo recomendable usar el término en su idioma original que no da lugar a dudas de lo que se está hablando, por lo que no veo problema en las ediciones de este usuario. A los que promovéis el uso este término, ¿por qué no lo proponéis a la Real Academia de la Lengua? En cuanto aparezca en el diccionario yo dejo de llamarlo array y le empiezo a llamar arreglo, pero mientras tanto, no.

Comment: @ordago buen punto pero estamos hablando de que el comportamiento del usuario es inusual y molesto. Al menos a varios nos resulta molesto. Si quieres puedes abrir una discusión sobre el término correcto para referirse a **array** aunque probablemente este no sea el sitio adecuado.

Comment: no dejan de ser opiniones, hay pésimas traducciones que vienen de los años 70 y 80 del siglo pasado. el punto es si la edición mejora la visibilidad y comprensión. el español castellano es muy rico en expresiones para andar atandose a "traducciones" del tipo mnemónicos vestigios de una época donde el "aprendizaje" se basaba en la repetición mas que en la asimilación de conceptos

Comment: @ordago si nos ponemos tan técnicos, entonces también hay que tener en cuenta que en este estos términos son tecnicismos, es decir, palabras que son usadas en un campo o disciplina determinado y los cuales no tienen por qué estar recogidos en la RAE

Comment: @eferion y si nos ponemos tan laxos que cualquier palabra vale por ser tecnicismo, podríamos aceptar arrechucho, arrebol, arraigo... palabras que no tienen nada que ver (como arreglo) con el concepto de array, solo por que se parecen un poquito. Si vale cualquier cosa, pues también vale "array" por lo que insito, no creo que haya que hacer nada con el usuario que ha relizado estas ediciones, que en mi opinión mejoran (o si me apuras, dejan igual) los contenidos escritos por OP.

Comment: @ordago creo que estás siendo un poco extremista ... `array` es una palabra que todo programador usa y lee ... el punto no es usar cualquier término sino aquellos que tienen sentido en un momento dado. Está claro que la programación está muy influenciada por el inglés, dado que es en este lenguaje en el que se han desarrollado prácticamente todos los lenguajes de programación existentes. Si trabajásemos en frío industrial o mecánica, entonces estaríamos usando muy probablemente términología alemana...

Comment: La cosa es que haya una mejora significativa. Yo pregunté acá por ediciones que hizo el buen fedorqui en su momento a una respuesta mía. Y pues claro, si la intención es mejorar la respuesta, quedamos en que teníá sentido. Pero la palabra arreglo existe y arrasar el sitio por una preferencia personal no tiene razón de ser. Incluso cosas como la respuesta que hay acá, de cambiar var por let/const suenan a revisionismo histórico y vandalizan las respuestas; tiene más valor añadir respuestas que den cuenta de la evolución (en SO en inglés hacen exactamente eso y creo que da más información)

Comment: De cualquier modo, como dihe en cierta respuesta, la informalidad de este sitio está buena. Y usar alguna que otra palabra en ingles para explicar un concepto de programación sin equivalente en español, no es motivo para editar.

Comment: El equipo de moderacion se ha comunicado con el usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se crea un Lenguaje de programación; normalmente se hace en un idioma común / particular a la lengua materna o de uso internacional y se establecen una estructura / arquitectura.

Independientemente del Idioma se crean también:

Métodos.
Propiedades.
Parámetros.
Clases.
Etc.

Si la persona que crea el lenguaje de programación es el "padre de la creatura" normalmente el o sus colaboradores determinaran el nombre que le darán, lo mismo pasa con otros sistemas informáticos, paquetes o software.

Veamos algunos ejemplos:

1. Framework PHPCake NO es traducido a español como PHPPastel.
2. Método en php array_map NO se traduce como matriz_mapa.

Así como existen métodos y nombres; también existen propiedades y tipado básico, ejemplos:

Bool, Boolean: barbarismo ingles booleano. No se traduce a español ni en código ni en contexto.
Int, Integer: Entero; no se traduce en el código, se sigue declarando como Int.

Cuando se habla de estos elemento del lenguaje de programacion, de debe respetar la sintaxis y se habala del: Boolean o el Integer

Bajo este mismo concepto, no deberíamos traducir el tipado, ni hispanizar los lenguajes de programación que fueron creados en su idioma nativo. Cuando hablamos de array, estamos hablando de un tipado de un lenguaje... y no de su elemento de traducción (aunque exista).

Si alguien crease un lenguaje de programacion y decide nativamente crear un "dato de tipo" Käse para representar el estado de un Dato Cuantico ... en pocas palabras se debe respetar el tecnicismo, el idioma y el contexto como fue diseñado.

***Update***

Aqui les dejo un ejemplo en donde el usuario en cuestion daño el codigo de una pregunta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/207727/revisions

y esa edicion paso por las manos de los revisores del sitio que habia rechazado el cambio, pero fue el mismo autor que luego aprobo el cambio dada la insistencia del Usuario, en este caso convertia todo lo que decia en Arreglo a Array pero agregaba espacios como si se tratace de un bot o auto corrector.

***Exactamente lo que me temia crea errores de tipado donde no los hay:***

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nota que no estamos hablando específicamente de los tipos en un lenguaje. Sino más sobre cómo nombramos las variables o nos referimos a diferentes conceptos. No veo impedimento para usar la palabra más apropiada en nuestro idioma en caso de que la haya.

Comment: si he visto las modificaciones y cambia el tipado. eso es un error. si estoy en php debo hablar de Array el usuario lo Cambia por Matriz... hispanisando el tipado en la explicacion o contexto.

Comment: Alguien ya hizo algo para detener a este editor?

Comment: @DanteS. dice que ya conversaron con el los moderadores: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62985751#62985751

Comment: Ya veo. Gracias por aclararmelo.

Comment: De la modificación que enseñas lo único reprochable en mi opinión sería que cambie el nombre de la variable que podría llegar afectar al funcionamiento en programas muy grandes que solo se enseña una parte, siendo esta una palabra no reservada por el lenguaje

Answer (score 0):

No sé si para bien o para mal, pero las ediciones en SOes son en base al criterio personal de quien las edita y quien las aprueba. Sin más les pondré un ejemplo reciente.

[image: Edición Reciente]

Lo que me parece aceptable: El cambio de **html** por **HTML** y corregir los errores ortográficos.

Lo que me parece cuestionable: Cambiar **responsivo** por **adaptable**. Señores este sitio es de informáticos y profesionales de la materia, todos entendemos y conocemos el diseño **RESPONSIVO**. ¿Por qué cambiarlo por una palabra, que a mi ver es menos técnica?

Lo que no me parece: El cambio de **tablets** por **tabletas** y **body** por **cuerpo**. Haciendo alusión a la respuesta anterior de **ArcanisGK507**, ¿no es mejor dejar los nombres propios (Tablet y body) como tal? Una tableta en español es algo completamente diferente (en su concepto más puro) de lo que es una **Tablet**. Además, creo que cambiar body por cuerpo es algo totalmente erróneo.

Y por último, pero no menos importante, ¿Por qué quitar los agradecimientos? ¿Acaso es un error o está mal agradecer de antemano?

Al final de todo, aún con las correcciones hechas, la pregunta fue cerrada porque, según los que votaron por el cierre, no es contenido adecuado para este sitio.

Comment: "¿Por qué quitar los agradecimientos?" basicamente porque son ruido, y no aportan nada a la pregunta. miar [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1334/324)

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo leí y aunque según veo en el topic, están mas en contra de eliminarlas veo que eso viene desde "mas arriba" como dicen. Mi duda sobre las cortesías (aunque no lo comparto) lo tomo como aceptado. Gracias por el interesante post.

Comment: Creo que debiste haber tapado la reputación y las medallas también si tu objetivo era que no se pueda reconocer el dueño de la edición. Puedo buscar el usuario por reputación. No es difícil encontrar a alguien con más de 10k

Comment: @Mateo, listo. Gracias por el dato.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que estuvo mal editada en todo lo que mencionaste, excepto en los agradecimientos. No quiero verlos, no quiero perder tiempo leyendo adornos a la pregunta, quiero un sitio donde pueda leer una pregunta objetiva, y no subjetiva. No me importa quién la publicó ni qué hora del día era, ni quiero que me salude, y más aún, no me interesa en lo más mínimo cuán agradecido esté. Directo al grano, cuál es el problema y cómo se soluciona. Si hubiese editado yo, no hubiese hecho ninguna de las malas traducciones, pero sí hubiese eliminado el "*¿alguien podría ayudarme?*"

Comment: Creo que lo de las "cortesías" ya quedo claro. Así que no le presten mas atención a esa parte.

Answer (score -4):

A quien corresponda: Me parece que a dicho usuario debería restringírsele el derecho de edición. La razón no es por el hecho de corregir el término usado (yo  creo que debiera ser array, que es la palabra restringida del lenguaje) si no por el hecho de reintentar hacerlo. Si nos ponemos puristas también habría que normalizar el uso de `var` en estradas antiguas (y algunas no tanto) por `const` o `let` para promover buenas prácticas. El lenguaje ha evolucionado y las preguntas, respuestas y ejemplos no.
¿Sería interesante crear una etiqueta versión en la que se recopilasen las mejores respuestas actualizando el lenguaje?